# How to do simple self join and touches function in postgis?

Tags: postgis, spatial-query

I am having trouble with this query and neighbor calculation in PostGIS. I want to find out which are the neighbors of Sweden in the table COUNTRIES which has column 'the_geom' for geometry and 'cntry_name' for countries. This is what I tried to do but with little success. Can someone explain to me what am I missing?

```
SELECT s1.cntry_name
FROM countries AS s1, countries AS s2 
WHERE s1.cntry_name = ‘Sweden’ AND
touches(s1.the_geom, s2.the_geom);
```

After editing the query this got me two results, Finland and Norway!

```
SELECT s1.cntry_name as sweden_neighbors
FROM countries AS s1, countries AS s2 
WHERE touches(s1.the_geom, s2.the_geom) = 'True' 
AND s2.cntry_name = 'Sweden';
```

Comment: Touches is strict because it does not allow overlaps at all. Only one vertex in your data going a few centimeters inside the neighboring country would drop the country from the result. Perhaps your data are not topologically clean? Try what you get with "Intersects".

Comment: @user30184 thank you for reply. Tried intersect but still no results. Is my query correct, maybe I missed something since I am beginner in this field.

Comment: ST_Intersects should have at least gotten you Sweden.  You sure your casing is right for 'Sweden'.  Does cntry_name = 'Sweden' get you anything?

Comment: Other possibility is your geometries are invalid. Try doing an ST_IsValid(the_geom) check.  Invalid geometries often return false for relationship checks.

Comment: @LR1234567 thanks for the suggestions. I tried even the simple query like SELECT countries.cntry_name as country, 
from countries
where country = 'Sweden'; and it doesn't show anything, no error also. IsValid also doesn't work? Could it be that there is something wrong with the database? thank you

Comment: @LR1234567 I've managed to get the basic query result and indeed it is 'Sweden' so the casing is right!!! any idea what next? thx

Comment: Please post the correction -- and mention the simple vs smart quote issue -- as an answer. (You're allowed to answer own question.) Then we and the system will know it is answered.

Answer (score 4):

Looser relation, but probably good enough:

```
SELECT s2.cntry_name as sweden_neighbors
FROM countries AS s1, countries AS s2 
WHERE ST_Intersects(s1.the_geom, s2.the_geom)
AND s1.cntry_name = 'Sweden'
AND s1.cntry_name != s2.cntry_name;
```

If you have actual gaps between your countries, you could use a ST_DWithin relationship to be looser still (use carefully, the units of dwithin are the units of your underlying projection, so in lon/lat, one unit is one degree (large)).

```
SELECT s2.cntry_name as sweden_neighbors
FROM countries AS s1, countries AS s2 
WHERE ST_DWithin(s1.the_geom, s2.the_geom,0.0001)
AND s1.cntry_name = 'Sweden'
AND s1.cntry_name != s2.cntry_name;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, appreciate it!!! I will  try this to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

HighPurpose,

ST_IsValid returns nothing - should return true or false if you have a geometry? Could it be you have no geometries.  To test for the obvious do the below query. That should return:

```
Sweden   true    false
```

if it doesn't then something is wrong (if the_geom is null returns true, then you have no geometry at all which would explain why even Sweden doesn't intersect itself.)  If its invalid (ST_ISvalid(..) = false) that would also explain why Sweden doesn't intersect itself.

Try this:

```
SELECT cntry_name, ST_IsValid(the_geom), the_geom IS NULL
 FROM countries 
 WHERE cntry_name = 'Sweden';
```

Comment: thx, this is useful for a newbie like me! cheers